# Generating dynamic root pages nextjs & contentful

Tags: reactjs, next.js, contentful

I seem to have a problem trying to generate root pages dynamically using contentfuls slug field and `getStaticPaths`. For example im trying to generate pages such as /products /about /press etc...

Now I have the page currently named index.tsx. I have tried [index].tsx, [slug].tsx [id].tsx and I seem to get different errors from each one. So I am not sure what to really do or if im even going into the right direction.

This is my page structure.

[image]

This is the code in the index page.

```
export async function getAllPages() {
  const client = createClient({
    space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  });

  const pages = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: 'page',
    include: 10,
    // 'fields.slug[in]': router.pathname
    'fields.slug[in]': '/'
  })

  return pages?.items?.map(item => {
    const fields = item.fields;
    return {
      title: fields.title,
      slug: fields.slug,
      seo: fields.seo,
      homepage: fields.homepage,
      pageBuilder: fields.pageBuilder || null
    }
  })

}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const pages = await getAllPages();

  let paths = pages.map((page) => ({
      params: {
          page: page.slug
      }
  }));

  return {
      paths,
      fallback: true
  }
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const pages = await getAllPages();

  return {
    props: { pages },
  };
};

export default function Home ({pages, slug}) {
  console.log('pages', pages)

  return (
  <>
    <StandardHead
      title="Computer Vision Platform"
      metaDescription="alwaysAI is a Computer Vision platform that provides enterprise developers with a simple and flexible way to deliver deep learning Computer Vision to a wide variety of Edge devices."
    />
    <Layout>
      <PageBuilder props={pages[0].pageBuilder}/>
    </Layout>
  </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is that your `/pages/index.js` file? `getStaticPaths` can only be used in dynamic routes. If you're passing `page.slug` as `page` in `getStaticPaths` params object, then your dynamic path should be `[page].js` to match it.